# Running of code for triangle after user input

Tags: java

im doing an assignment and would require to user to input 3 number int 1-9 and then determine if it is a triangle

- (a=4, b=5, c=6 is a triangle)
- (a=1, b=2, c=2 is not a triangle)

and from there determine if it is an

1. Equilateral (3 sides are equal)
2. Isosceles (2 side are equal)
3. Scalene (3 sides are different)
4. NotTriangle

the code i've done so far has some troubles running them which i cant seem to identify where is the problem. it keeps coming out with errors from the sub class method named `displayInfo` which links via method `isTriangle2` & `getType` to determine both if it is a triangle and which type if it is.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
The method printf(String, Object...) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, void)

at PossibleTriangle.displayInfo(Test.java:187)
at Test.main(Test.java:225)
```

here is my full code for reference:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

enum Type {EQUILATERAL, ISOSCELES, SCALENE, NOTTRIANGLE}

// S T A R T   T R I A N G L E   C L A S S

class PossibleTriangle
{
    // Declare instance variables related to Health Profile
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;
    private Type pt;
    
    // Default Constructor
    public PossibleTriangle ()
    {
        //by default    
    }
    
    // Other Constructor
    public PossibleTriangle  (int a, int b, int c)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    
    
    // Copy Constructor
    public PossibleTriangle (PossibleTriangle p)
    {
        this(p.a, p.b, p.c);
    }

    // Accessor Methods
    
    public int getA ()
    {
        return a;
    }
    
    public int getB ()
    {
        return b;
    }
    
    public int getc ()
    {
        return c;
    }
    
    public Type getPt ()
    {
        return pt;
    }
    
    // Mutator Methods
    public void setInfo (int a, int b, int c, Type pt)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.pt = pt;
    }
    
    
    private boolean isTriangle (int a, int b, int c)
    {   
        if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (b + c <= a))
            return true;
        
        else    
            return false;
    }
    
    private void isTriangle2 (int a, int b, int c)
    {
        
        if ((isTriangle(a,b,c)) == true)
            System.out.printf("Valid Triangle%n"); 
        else
            System.out.printf("Not a Triangle%n"); 
    }
    

    private static Type getType2 (int a, int b, int c, Type pt)
    {
        // Divide character set into four types
        if ((a == b) && (b == c) && (c == a)) {
            return Type.EQUILATERAL;
            
        } else if ((a == b && b != c) || (a != b && c == a) || (c==b && c != a)) {
            return  Type.ISOSCELES;
            
        } else if ((a != b) && (b != c) && (c != a)) {
            return  Type.SCALENE;
            
        } else {
            return  Type.NOTTRIANGLE;
        }
    }

    
    private void getType (Type pt)
    {       
        
        switch (pt){
        
        case EQUILATERAL: System.out.printf("Equilateral Triangle");
                                break;
                          
        case ISOSCELES:   System.out.printf("Isosceles Triangle");
                                break;
        
        case SCALENE:     System.out.printf("Scalene Triangle");
                                break;

        default:          System.out.printf("Not a triangle");
                                break;
                    }
    }
    
    // Display method
    public void displayInfo ()
    {       
        PossibleTriangle t = new PossibleTriangle (a, b, c);
        
        System.out.printf ("\tCharacter is %n. Its type is " , this.getType(pt));
    }

}   
// E N D   T R I A N G L E   C L A S S



// S T A R T   M A I N   C L A S S    
class Test
{   
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {   
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        Type pt;
        
        // READ FIRST TRIANGLE
        
        System.out.printf ("Enter 3 numbers: ");
        a = input.next ().charAt (0);
            
        b = input.next ().charAt (0);
            
        c = input.next ().charAt (0);
    
        
        PossibleTriangle p = new PossibleTriangle (a, b, c);
        p.displayInfo();


        // READ SECOND TRIANGLE
        
        System.out.printf ("%nEnter 3 numbers: ");
        a = input.next ().charAt (0);
            
        b = input.next ().charAt (0);
            
        c = input.next ().charAt (0);

    
    }
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to convert it to switch ?

Comment: Aside from the question about switch: the if/else code would not detect an equilateral triangle, it would say it was isoceles instead.

Comment: Adding the if else statements after the switch isn't needed, and can be combined with the case.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What is your input? Do you expect 3 lengths as input and a result? Can you elaborate, please. I don't understand how testing on the enum can give you this result unless that's another input.

Comment: @Scratte have updated my question with more detailed information. thank you!

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi the assignment was to explore use of Switch method and else if methods

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to find out what your assignment is by reading your description, but it seems that you need to write two methods:

- A method `Type getType(int a, int b, int c)` which returns the type of the triangle given the parameters `a`, `b` and `c`. This method would use an `if`-`else` statement.
- A method which displays the type given a `Type` object. This method would use a `switch` statement.

It will look something like this:

```
private static Type getType(int a, int b, int c) {
    if ( /* condition 1 */ ) {
        return NOTTRIANGLE;
    } else if ...
        ...
        ...
}

private static void displayAnalysis() {
    int a = /* ... */ ;
    int b = /* ... */ ;
    int c = /* ... */ ;
    Type type = getType(a, b, c); // <-- here getType is called to determine the type
    switch (type) {
        case NOTTRIANGLE:
            ...
            break;
        case EQUILATERAL;
            ...
            break;
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that the conditions in an `if`-`else` statement and checked in order, and that the rest of the conditions is not checked as soon as one conditions is satisfied. So, you need to think about in what order to check for the different types of triangle.

Comment: what should i do if i wanted to get user to input their own numbers ranging 1-9 instead of setting the int a, int b, int c in the codes. im sorry i just started learning Java this month and need it for my assignment >.<

Comment: @Soph: You can use a Scanner. Read my answer: i've added a code that you can use to get what you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this solution is the best.
First of all, we have to understand how the switch works (read the [Oracle switch page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)). Look at this image:

[image: image1]

Every case statement is **indipendent**, so you can't use `if...else` accross the switch case.
The correct form is:

```
switch (Type){

    case CASE1: //op1;
                break;
                 
    case CASE2: //op2;
                break;
            
        [ . . . ]
            
    case CASE N: //opN;
                 break;

}//switch
```

Note that we have to write **break;** at the end of every block.

When you use a switch you are already doing a job similar to an `if-else`, so you should not use the switch to do other checks of this type.
You, probably, have to save the current `Type` in a variable (depending from the conditions) and use the switch to indicate what operations to perform.

For example:

```
enum Type {EQUILATERAL, ISOSCELES, SCALENE, NOTTRIANGLE}

/*
 int a = ...
 int b = ...
 int c = ...
*/

Type currentType = EQUILATERAL;

/*Now check the type of the triangle... I don't want to change your code, 
 but there are some errors in the conditions (the second "else" must be
 written before the first else...)
*/
if ((a + b <= c) || (a + c <= b) || (b + c <= a)) {
    currentType=NOTTRIANGLE;
} else if ((a == b) || (b == c) || (c == a)) {
    currentType=ISOSCELES;
} else if ((a == b) && (b == c) && (c == a)) {
    currentType=EQUILATERAL;
} else {
    currentType=SCALENE
}

//Now you can use the switch


switch (currentType){

case NOTTRIANGLE:   System.out.printf("Not a triangle");
                    //other operations
                    break;
             
case ISOSCELES:     System.out.printf("Isosceles Triangle");
                    //other operations
                    break;   
        
case EQUILATERAL:   System.out.printf("Equilateral Triangle");
                    //other operations
                    break;

default:    System.out.printf("Scalene Triangle");
            //other operations
            break;
}
```

You can, obviously, put the if-else statement and the switch in different methods and call it from the main method.

---

If you want to get the 3 numbers as a user input, you can use **java.util.Scanner;** and its method **nextInt()**, that allows to read a number digited by the user.

Here's the code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter A: ");
int a = sc.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter B: ");
int b = sc.nextInt(); 
System.out.print("Enter C: ");
int c = sc.nextInt();
```